# Flash builder 4.7 invalid or missing signing information

Tags: android, air, flash-builder

I just upgraded Flash builder from 4.6 to 4.7, Imported my previous 4.6 project, tested it, works fine, went to Project > Export Release Build, made the same Export build, signed with the same p12 certificate file, uploaded to Google Play and... Im getting a:

```
Upload failed
You uploaded an APK with invalid or missing signing information for some of its files. You need to create a valid signed APK. Learn more about signing.
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, hast anyone been through the same?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

found this website,[here](http://k2xl.com/wordpress/you-uploaded-an-apk-with-invalid-or-missing-signing-information-for-some-of-its-files-google-play-adobe-air-error/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20DannyMillerInteractiveBlog%20%28Danny%20Miller%20Interactive%20Blog%29) followed steps... Succes! yeyyy!

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Flex [Apache 4.9](http://flex.apache.org/), it the latest release and it's working with flash 4.7.
Also try creating new environment for Flash 4.7 and import your work there.

Comment: I tried it but with no luck, Im using FB 4.7 Air 3.7 and Apache flex 4.9.1